# jquery datepicker - prevent mouseover event when setting defaultDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have set up a jquery datepicker which jumps to a default date. This is simple enough, however, I've also got a mouseover event attached to each selectable date. Therefore, when the datepicker sets the default date, it also triggers the mouseover event.

Is there any way of preventing this from happening only when it jumps to that date?

Here's a fiddle which should make it clearer... The alert should occur on mouseover but not when the datepicker is opened.

http://jsfiddle.net/Gyztj/

And here's my code (because it insists I include it)

```
function dateDiffInDays(a, b) {
  // Discard the time and time-zone information.
  var utc1 = Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate());
  var utc2 = Date.UTC(b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth(), b.getDate());

  return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
}

var firstStartDate;

$('.Cal').datepicker({

        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: '+2Y',
        numberOfMonths: 1,

        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
            startDates = [];            
            selectdatesElem = $(input).siblings("select.startdates");   
            firstStartDate = selectdatesElem.find("option:eq(1)").val().split(', ');
            $(input).datepicker('option','defaultDate',dateDiffInDays(new Date(), new Date(parseInt(firstStartDate[1], 10) + "/" + parseInt(firstStartDate[2], 10) + "/" + parseInt(firstStartDate[0], 10))));

            $(input).siblings("select.startdates").find("option").each( function() {
                  startdateParts = $(this).val().split(', ');
                  startDates.push(startdateParts[0] + ", " + (parseInt(startdateParts[1], 10)-1) + ", " + parseInt(startdateParts[2], 10));
            }); 

        },

        beforeShowDay: function(date) {         
            for (i = 0; i < startDates.length; i++) {
                  if (date.getFullYear()+", "+date.getMonth()+", "+date.getDate() == startDates[i]) {
                        return [true, 'eventDay'];
                  }
            }           
            return [false, ''];
        }
    });

$(document).on("mouseover", "td.eventDay", function() {
        alert("Hello World!")
    });
```

and

```
<input class='Cal' />

<select name="startDates"  id="startDates" class="startdates">
    <option selected="selected" value="%">%</option>
    <option value="2013, 11, 01">C1</option>
    <option value="2013, 11, 08">C1</option>
    <option value="2013, 11, 11">C1</option>
    <option value="2013, 11, 18">C1</option>
    <option value="2013, 11, 29">C1</option>
    <option value="2013, 11, 25">C1</option>
    <option value="2013, 12, 06">C1</option>

</select>
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the mouseover event ?

Comment: It's a custom tooltip which pops up on mouseover, but for the purpose of this question I didn't think it was all that important. I can add the code in if it will help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the most hacky solution ever.But because datepicker api uses mouseover from initialization, this is the only thing i could come up with :

```
$(document).on("mouseover", "td.eventDay", function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("ui-datepicker-days-cell-over")){
        //alert("do nothing");
        $(this).removeClass('ui-datepicker-days-cell-over');
    }
    else{
        alert("hacky solution should work");
    }
    });
```

So basicly when you set the default date, jquery triggers a mouseover to focus on that day, and adds a `ui-datepicker-days-cell-over` class to that `td`. Though, i am not sure how to enable mouseover again on the default date, without breaking anything.(because i don't know what exactly the `ui-datepicker-cell-over` class is used for  )

Comment: As hacky as it is, it seems to work, so I'll go with it! Thanks

Comment: I've tried ataching a tooltip to eventDay, it works, but for some reason only on the second mouseover [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/Gyztj/1/) :/, good luck !

Comment: Nice... I didn't know about the .tooltip thing! I achieved it like this... http://jsfiddle.net/D3MHW/